# Parsing XML using XmlPullParser for specific tags?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

Hey I have just started work on XML parsing in android. I am working 
 on xml which has a structure like this.

```
        <quran>
        <sura index="113" name="الفلق">
                <aya index="1" text="قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ الْفَلَقِ" bismillah="بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ" />
                <aya index="2" text="مِنْ شَرِّ مَا خَلَقَ" />
                <aya index="3" text="وَمِنْ شَرِّ غَاسِقٍ إِذَا وَقَبَ" />
                <aya index="4" text="وَمِنْ شَرِّ النَّفَّاثَاتِ فِي الْعُقَدِ" />
                <aya index="5" text="وَمِنْ شَرِّ حَاسِدٍ إِذَا حَسَدَ" />
            </sura>
            <sura index="114" name="الناس">
                <aya index="1" text="قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ النَّاسِ" bismillah="بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ" />
                <aya index="2" text="مَلِكِ النَّاسِ" />
                <aya index="3" text="إِلَهِ النَّاسِ" />
                <aya index="4" text="مِنْ شَرِّ الْوَسْوَاسِ الْخَنَّاسِ" />
                <aya index="5" text="الَّذِي يُوَسْوِسُ فِي صُدُورِ النَّاسِ" />
                <aya index="6" text="مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ" />
            </sura>
        </quran>
```

Now in my first class I just want to show a list view in which just 
name of a sura is mentioned, which I have done successfully using this 
code.

```
 XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.quran_arabic);

        while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("sura")) {
                list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + ".\n" + parser.getAttributeValue(1));
            }
            parser.next();
        }
```

In my lisview only name of sura is showing now I want to show the aya tags of specific sura on which user will click.
In my next activity I am using this code

```
 XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.quran_arabic);

        while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("aya")) {
                list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + ".\n" + parser.getAttributeValue(1));
            }
            parser.next();
        }
```

But I am getting all aya tags attributes instead of specific sura. Please help me to get just those aya which is present on a specific tag on which user will clicked. I just posted 2 tags of sura in xml actually i have 114 so please help me to use the right code. Sorry I am not good in english. Just help me out. Thanks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all `aya` tags inside given `sura`, then you should write a method that take `sura index` as input for example 113 or 114 and return all `aya` tags as output.

```
private List<String> getAllAyaFromSuraIndex(String suraIndex) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.quran_arabic);
    while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("sura")) {
            String index = parser.getAttributeValue(0);

            // Match given sure index
            if (index.equals(suraIndex)) {
                // Move to first aya tag inside matched sura index
                parser.next();

                // This loop will exit when it reaches sura end tag </sura>
                while (parser.getName().equals("aya")) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + ".\n" + parser.getAttributeValue(1));
                    }

                    // Move to next aya tag
                    parser.next();
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        parser.next();
    }

    return list;
}
```